Asignar datos a una variable procedentes de un JSON en C#
en la actulidad tenemos dificultades para asignar datos a 4 variables. Consideramos que haciendo correctamente una de estas asignaciones, las demas tambien seran corregidas porque todas presentan la misma novedad.
Consideramos importante mostrar el una pequeña muestra del JSON del cual tomamos los datos:
[
  {
    "uniqueID": 1116804644,
    "plate": "VD-227",
    "GPSDate": "2024-10-21T06:39:18.000Z",
    "latitude": 1.18963,
    "longitude": -76.64931,
    "speed": 0,
    "course": 0,
    "odometer": 25823.429,
    "receivedDate": "2024-10-21T06:39:19.000Z",
    "stateInfo": {
      "stateData": {
        "stateParam": "11+",
        "stateDetail": "Parado"
      }
    },
    "GPSQuality": 1,
    "CANInfo": {
      "CANData": [
        {
          "CANParam": "fuelLevel1",
          "CANValue": "72"
        },
        {
          "CANParam": "RPM",
          "CANValue": "0"
        },
        {
          "CANParam": "speed",
          "CANValue": "0"
        },
        {
          "CANParam": "coolantTemperature",
          "CANValue": "80"
        }
      ]
    },
    "peripheralsInfo": {
      "peripheralsData": [
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Motor",
          "peripheralsValue": "Parado"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Bateria",
          "peripheralsValue": "Cargando"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Pedal panico",
          "peripheralsValue": "off"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Inmovilizador",
          "peripheralsValue": "Bloqueado"
        }
      ]
    },
    "geofenceInfo": {
      "geofenceData": {
        "geofencePoint": "PUNTO 161",
        "geofencePolygon": "UF5-6-7 VAR SANFRANCISCO"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "uniqueID": 1116940862,
    "plate": "VD-207",
    "GPSDate": "2024-10-21T06:35:37.000Z",
    "latitude": 6.82334,
    "longitude": -74.78653,
    "speed": 0,
    "course": 0,
    "odometer": 27759.361,
    "receivedDate": "2024-10-21T16:13:52.000Z",
    "stateInfo": {
      "stateData": {
        "stateParam": "11+",
        "stateDetail": "Parado"
      }
    },
    "GPSQuality": 1,
    "CANInfo": {
      "CANData": [
        {
          "CANParam": "adblueLevel",
          "CANValue": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    "peripheralsInfo": {
      "peripheralsData": [
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Motor",
          "peripheralsValue": "Parado"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Bateria",
          "peripheralsValue": "Cargando"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Pedal panico",
          "peripheralsValue": "off"
        },
        {
          "peripheralsParam": "Inmovilizador",
          "peripheralsValue": "Bloqueado"
        }
      ]
    },
    "geofenceInfo": {
      "geofenceData": {
        "geofencePoint": "PUNTO 159",
        "geofencePolygon": "MAG2_ZonaOperativa"
      }
    }
  }
]

Estos son las clases que estamos utilizando:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class vehicleInfo
    {
        public long uniqueID { get; set; }
        public string? plate { get; set; }
        public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
        public float latitude { get; set; }
        public float longitude { get; set; }
        public int speed { get; set; }
        public int course { get; set; }
        public float odometer { get; set; }
        public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
        public stateData? stateInfo { get; set; }
        public int GPSQuality { get; set; }
        public CANInfo? CANInfo { get; set; }
        public peripheralsInfo? peripheralsInfo { get; set; }
        public geofenceData? geofenceInfo { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DAL
{
    public class stateData
    {
        public string? stateParam { get; set; }
        public string? stateDetail { get; set; }
    }
}

using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace DAL
{
    public class GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Registro { get; set; }   
        public long uniqueID { get; set; }
        public string? plate { get; set; }
        public DateTime GPSDate { get; set; }
        public int speed { get; set; }
        [Precision(53)]
        [Column(TypeName = "float(53)")]
        public float odometer { get; set; }
        public DateTime receivedDate { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamAlarmaLimiteVelocidad { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamAlarmaACLAceleracionBrusca { get; set; }
        public string? stateParamAlarmaACLFrenadaBrusca { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueTotalFuel { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueFuelLevel1 { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueRPM { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueOdometer { get; set; }
        public string? CANValuesSpeed { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueCoolantTemperature { get; set; }
        public string? CANValueAmbientAirTemperature { get; set; }  
        public string? CANValueEngineHours { get; set; }
        public string? peripheralsValueMotor { get; set; }
        public string? geofencePolygon { get; set; }
        public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
    }
}

Luego de presentar las clases, procedemos a presentar el metodo encargado de asignarle los datos a cada variable.
/// <summary>
        /// 2024-11-15 11:00: Transformar los datos del JSON deserializados a los del tipo utilizado en la tabla. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="info"></param>
        /// <returns>Datos tabla</returns>
        public GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet(vehicleInfo info) => new GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet
        {
            uniqueID = info.uniqueID,
            plate = info.plate,
            GPSDate = info.GPSDate,
            speed = info.speed,
            odometer = info.odometer,
            receivedDate = info.receivedDate,
            stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "261")?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaLimiteVelocidad = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "35+")?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaACLAceleracionBrusca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "214")?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaACLFrenadaBrusca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "213")?.stateDetail,
            CANValueTotalFuel = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "totalFuel")?.CANValue,
            CANValueFuelLevel1 = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "fuelLevel1")?.CANValue,
            CANValueRPM = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "RPM")?.CANValue,
            CANValueOdometer = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "odometer")?.CANValue,
            CANValuesSpeed = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "speed")?.CANValue,
            CANValueCoolantTemperature = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "coolantTemperature")?.CANValue,
            CANValueAmbientAirTemperature = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "ambientAirTemperature")?.CANValue,
            CANValueEngineHours = info.CANInfo?.CANData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.CANParam == "engineHours")?.CANValue,
            peripheralsValueMotor = info.peripheralsInfo?.peripheralsData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.peripheralsParam == "Motor")?.peripheralsValue,
            geofencePolygon = info.geofenceInfo?.geofencePolygon,
            FechaInsert = DateTime.Now
        };

Antes de compilar, notamos que se presentan 4 errores que son:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'stateData' does not contain a definition for 'stateData' and no accessible extension method 'stateData' accepting a first argument of type 'stateData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BIL E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL\Methods.cs  141 Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'stateData' does not contain a definition for 'stateData' and no accessible extension method 'stateData' accepting a first argument of type 'stateData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BIL E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL\Methods.cs  142 Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'stateData' does not contain a definition for 'stateData' and no accessible extension method 'stateData' accepting a first argument of type 'stateData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BIL E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL\Methods.cs  143 Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'stateData' does not contain a definition for 'stateData' and no accessible extension method 'stateData' accepting a first argument of type 'stateData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BIL E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL\Methods.cs  144 Active

Como se puede notar, los 4 errores son del mismo tipo, el cual esta relacionado con estas 4 lineas:
stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "261")?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaLimiteVelocidad = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "35+")?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaACLAceleracionBrusca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "214")?.stateDetail,
            stateParamAlarmaACLFrenadaBrusca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "213")?.stateDetail,

En primer lugar, intentamos seguiendo la ruta de acceso a los datos teniendo presente la clase stateInfo, luego stateData y por ultimo hicimos un filtro para obtener el dato de interes asi: FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "261")?.stateDetail.
Como el interes es poder asignarle el dato correcto a cada variable, es relevente aplicarle el filtro.
Aun no hemos identificado la forma correcta de asignar estos datos, por lo que agradecemos la ayuda que nos puedan brindar.

que es stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca ??? en todo esta maraña de codigo, justo el error es lo unico que no esta definido en ningun lado...

Muestra por favor la definición de la clase GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet

Saludos. De lo que observo; stateData es un tipo de dato así como vehicleInfo; ésta última tiene una propiedad stateInfo que es de tipo stateData; tengo la sensación que info.stateInfo?.stateData?.... no existe e ignoro como se compila; ademas que no es un List, Collection... un Array de donde pides tomar el primer elemento o te devuelva nulo. Lo que sí existe es info.stateInfo?.stateParam y info.stateInfo?.stateDetail.

Hola @Arriel, ya incluimos la clase GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet en la pregunta.

Hola @RobertoLeOr, es como lo mencionas, al colocar la variable as stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfo?.stateDetail, se quita el error, pero mi duda continua, ya que como puedes notar, info.stateInfo?.stateDetail entrega varios tipos de resultado y los que nos interesa almacenar en esta variable o compo son los que cumplen con stateParam == "261", esto como lo puedo hacer.

Hola @gbianchi, se edita la pregunta donde se incluye la clase donde se define los paremetros.

Me parece que aca el problema esta mal encarado y habria una forma mejor (esto ya es pura opinion) en realidad, vos deberias parsear automaticamente tu JSON a una clase que lo acepte asi como esta, y luego, si queres por ejemplo un dato en particular, tener propiedades que lo devuelvan si existe.. o nulo si no existe. De esa forma, te ahorras todos estos problemas que estas teniendo. Imagina tener una propiedad readonly que devuelve el valor que estas buscando solo si existe. Para que tener mil variables dando vueltas en nulo, si en realidad son datos de lectura... o no?

@GermanDavid, ya Roberto respondió tu pregunta. Según el JSOIN stateInfo es un objeto, que contiene otro objeto stateData que tiene dos propiedades string. Por eso es que no puedes utilizar IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault(), (al menos no el método de extensión de Linq, porque podrías tener uno propio con el mismo nombre que podría ser la peor idea del mundo). Cambialo por stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.stateParam.Equals("214") ? info.stateInfo?.stateData?.stateDetail : null, y así con los otros según corresponda

Hola @gbianchi, pensamos que cuando nos indicas parsear, se refiere a deserializar el JSON. Si estamos en lo correcto, ya fue realizada esta labor. Luego esos datos los convertimos al tipo tabla que deseamos insertar datos posteriormente, para lo cual utilizamos una funcion de transformacion recomendada por usted. Aun continuamos con la novedad mencionada en la presgunta.

Edit:
Aunque la respuesta original es técnicamente correcta, tu problema en realidad es que la clase vehicleInfo SÍ TIENE una propiedad stateInfo de tipo stateData, PERO el tipo stateData NO TIENE una propiedad llamada stateData. Probablemente por los problemas de compilación no has tenido la oportunidad de deserializar el JSON a vehicleInfo, pero te puedo decir que probablemente no funcione.
Si intentas crear la POCO desde el JSON, ya sea en Visual Studio con 'Paste Special', o con una herramienta en línea, te vas a dar cuenta que la clase vehicleInfo quedaría así:
public class vehicleInfo
    {
         // ... otras propiedades
       
         public stateInfo stateInfo { get; set; }
         public int GPSQuality { get; set; }
         //... el resto de propiedades
     }

public class stateData
     {
         public string stateParam { get; set; }
         public string stateDetail { get; set; }
     }

public class stateInfo
     {
         public stateData stateData { get; set; }
     }

Qué te quiero decir con esto? Que la clase que creaste para deserializar no te va a funcionar porque, efectivamente como el compilador dice:
'stateData' does not contain a definition for 'stateData'...
Lo que el compilador no te dice es la clase stateData solo tiene stateParam y stateDetail
En la clase vehicleInfo cambia:
public stateData? stateInfo { get; set; }

por
public stateInfo? stateInfo { get; set; }

y verás cómo se resuelven tus problemas.
Respuesta original:
Un resumen de los comentarios:
Según la estructura de tu JSON,
"stateInfo": {
  "stateData": {
    "stateParam": "11+",
    "stateDetail": "Parado"
  }

stateInfo es un objeto (de tipo stateData) que contiene un objeto llamado stateData (también de tipo stateData), que a su vez, tiene dos propiedades de tipo string stateParam y stateDetail. Cabe aclarar que stateData no es un arreglo. Esto es importante porque en la sentencia:
stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "261")?.stateDetail,
Estás llamando a .FirstOrDefault() sobre stateData que es una clase que no implementa IEnumerable, en pocas palabras stateData no es una lista o un arreglo u otra estructura que implemente esa interfaz.
Si tu y tu equipo escribieron un método de extensión con una firma public static stateData FirstOrDefault(this stateData, Func(stateData, bool));, eso no está incluído en los detalles de la pregunta, y dudo mucho que hayan escrito un método que se llame igual que el método de LINQ porque sería dirigir a los otros devs al pozo de las lágrimas.
En todo caso, lo que solucionaría el error que estás recibiendo sería evaluar correctamente el valor de la propiedad y asignar el valor correcto. Por ejemplo:
stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca =
   info.stateInfo?.stateData?.stateParam.Equals("11+") ?
   info.stateInfo?.stateData?.stateDetail : null

En palabras cristianas significa: "¿El valor de stateParam es igual a '11+'? Si es correcto, asígnale el valor que viene en stateDetail, de lo contrario, asigna null.
Esto para cada uno de las propiedades donde estás teniendo el error. Inténtalo y nos cuentas cómo te fue.
Takeaway:
IEnumerable.FirstOrDefault() es para objetos/tipos que implementan la interfaz IEnumerable<T>.

hola @Arriel, la solucion planteada nos esta generando este error: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). Esto sucede con la linea: stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.stateParam.Equals("11+") ?
info.stateInfo?.stateData?.stateDetail : null,

Intenta info.stateInfo?.stateData?.stateParam.Equals("11+").GetValueOrDefault(), y me cuentas

este es el error que nos sale ahora: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1501 No overload for method 'GetValueOrDefault' takes 0 arguments BIL E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL\Methods.cs 147 Active

@GermanDavid no se puede ir resolviendo tu duda asi como asi... en este caso, como en casi todos, el error te dice que esa funcion necesita algun parametro.. probaste leer la documentacion y fijarte que parametro necesita?? igual, el error de mas arriba deic que no se podia convertir un bool nullable en un bool.. bastaba con transformar uno en otro y listo...

Hola @Arriel, por favor edita tu respuesta ya que el error de CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool', logramos corregirlo cambiando .Equals por ==. En definitiva quedo asi: stateParamExcesoVelocidadGeocerca = info.stateInfo?.stateData?.stateParam == "11+" ? info.stateInfo?.stateData?.stateDetail : null, De esta forma, su respuesta sera escogida como la resolvio nuestra duda, pues fue muy detallada y nos permitio tener la guia para lograrlo.

Saludos.
De los 4 errores que se presentan.
Ya quedo que info.stateInfo?.stateData? no existe y entiendo ya corregiste.
Ahora lo que falta es el filtrar los datos respecto lo que deseas aplicar. Que cumplan con stateParam == "261".
Abordo por partes para establecer el como percibo tu escenarios.

Recibes información objetos en formado JSON (de "manera" simple) con la siguiente estructura: [{datos del objeto 1}, {datos del objeto 2}...{datos del objeto N}] (en el punto dos a continuación asumo y me salto el deserializar)
Obtienes un List/Array/Collection/Enumerate... con objetos vehicleInfo *(desde luego tantos como Objetos JSON recibiste).
Por simplicidad a continuación asumo que los objetos vehicleInfo están dentro de un List (para usar LinQ); ademas yo como/para guía le pongo a la variable lstVehicles (no encontré la misma en tu código; asumo que la identificas).


La función public GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet(vehicleInfo info) => new GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet no ubico donde la llamas.

Ahora con los puntos antes mencionado y usando las variables con los datos que planteo entiendo de tu escenario; primero es recorrer lstVehicles y tomar aquellos que te interesan procesar en tu función ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet (directamente sería):
List<GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet> miListaFinal = new List<GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet>();
lstVehicles.Where(w => (w.stateInfo?.stateParam??"") == "261" )
   .ToList()
   ForEach(item => { miListaFinal.Add(ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet(item)); 
});

OBSERVACIÓN
Del JSON que pones procesas tienes
"stateInfo": {
  "stateData": {
    "stateParam": "11+",
    "stateDetail": "Parado"
  }
}

afectivamente recibes stateInfo.stateData.stateParam; pero en tu objeto no lo tienes así definido; lo tienes como te señale existe stateInfo.stateParam; por ello la confusión que tienes y seguro errores al deserializar obtendrás advertencia sino es que errores.
Realiza el cambio de tal forma que ambos coincidan, tu JSON con tu clase vehicleInfo ¿Donde cambiar? Lo dejo a tu criterio, no quiero sugerirte cambios en tus estructuras; te corresponderá decidir donde hacer "qué" conforme sea/es necesario.
Algo parecido similar con CANInfo y peripheralsInfo tienes pero dentro en lugar de Info finalizan en Data; yo particularmente evito usar nombre de Clases a propiedades (o viceversa); aprovecha que C# distingue entre mayúsculas y minúsculas y (a tu criterio) cambia el nombre de la propiedad o la clase la primer letra a mayúscula para que identifiques.
Te sugiero la siguiente lectura Tipos de notación
ATENDIENDO COMENTARIO
En el contexto que usé; lstVehicles es una variable que yo cree; no es otra cosa más que el array/arreglo/matriz de JSON que recibes (sin profundizar y para simplificar) en un List en C# de clases vehicleInfo (como mencione que permite -agregando los using respectivos- LinQ). Por cualquier cosa va de nuevo, pero sin tanto detalle.
1. Recibes tu Array/Arreglo/matriz de elementos JSON
[
    {
        "uniqueID": 1116804644,
        "plate": "VD-227",
        "GPSDate": "2024-10-21T06:39:18.000Z",
        "latitude": 1.18963,
        "longitude": -76.64931,
        "speed": 0,
        "course": 0,
        "odometer": 25823.429,
        "receivedDate": "2024-10-21T06:39:19.000Z",
        "stateInfo": objeto,
        "GPSQuality": 1,
        /*otros*/
    },
    /* otros objetos; todos que C# son convertido/parse
    a del tipo vehicleInfo c/u */
]

2. El JSON lo pasas a Lista (List) de Objetos en C#; en este caso List de vehicleInfo
Es con el resultado de aquí (durante/con esta conversión/parse) la variable lstVehicles tiene el JSON recibidos pero en clases C#.

Desconozco como lo haces así; asumo que ya lo tienes completo dejarlo así.

3. Buscar los que interesa que son stateParam == "261"
Ésta parte, segun como quedara finalmente tu clase por la observación respecto a:
Del JSON que pones procesas tienes
"stateInfo": {
  "stateData": {
    "stateParam": "11+",
    "stateDetail": "Parado"
  }
}

Ya que inicialmente el error que tenias Error   CS1061  'stateData' does not contain a definition for 'stateData' and no accessible extension method 'stateData' accepting a first argument of type 'stateData' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BIL E:\TallerCentral\APIRESTClientFlotasNet\BIL\Methods.cs  141 Active dependiendo como quedo.
En el Where seguido del ForEach (mediante LinQ) ya que no reportaste error aquí sí queda el FirstOrDefault para CANInfo?.CANData? y peripheralsInfo?.peripheralsData? en tu función ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet.
Lo que no debe existir ya es el info.stateInfo?.stateData?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "261")?.stateDetail o info.stateInfo?.FirstOrDefault(a => a.stateParam == "261")?.stateDetail conforme según atendieras este punto... debe ser directo info.stateInfo?.stateDetail (repito conforme fue atendido); es así como llego a mi sugerencia de código:
List<GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet> miListaFinal = new List<GpsAPIRESTFlotasnet>();
lstVehicles.Where(w => (w.stateInfo?.stateParam??"") == "261" )
   .ToList()
   ForEach(item => { miListaFinal.Add(ToGpsAPIRESTFlotasnet(item)); 
});

Usando lstVehicles.

Hola RobertoLeOr, muchas gracias por las observaciones, lo primero que hicimos fue diferenciar entre clases y parametros, evitando usar el mismo nombre para ambos. En este punto no puede entender bien a que se refiere con "lstVehicles". Esa parte no me permitio entender bien como solucionar la situacion que tenemos actualmente.

Saludos. @GermanDavid actualice mi respuesta.
